# $query->limit(10) gives fatal error

Tags: 7, paging

I am trying to develop a simple module in Drupal 7. I want to return a table with some data in a function, which i am able to achieve. I am stuck in the pager part though.

I used

```
pager_default_initialize($total, 10);
$html .= theme('pager', array('quantity',$total));
```

and I can see the pager below my list, also I have 21 records for now and it shows << < 1 2 3 > >> which means it calculating 10 records each.

But my issue here is I can see all the 21 records at once regardless of whichever page I go to. I suppose I have goofed up my page_query.
When I tried using `$query->limit(10)` it gives error Fatal error:

> Call to undefined method SelectQuery::limit() in C:\xampp\htdocs...............

If I comment `$query->limit`, there's no error but it does not work completely.
This is my query

```
$query = db_select('profile');
$query->fields('profile', array('id', 'name', 'store_name', 'company', 'city', 'email', 'phone'));
$query->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
$query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(10);
//$query->limit(10);
$results = $query->execute();
```

Please help!

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extend()` isn't chain-able, it returns a new extended query object, so you need to assign the result back to the query object, e.g.

```
$query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(10);
```

Otherwise the query won't actually be extended and won't have the `limit()` method, hence the error you're getting.

Comment: Hi, your solution worked. The error is gone.  however now I cannot see the pager. Thx a ton.

Comment: Just to add I had to remove pager_default_initialize($total, 10); to make it work. so I used $query = $query->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(10);
 in the query and $html .= theme('pager', array('quantity',$total)); in my function. Works like a charm. \m/ thanks again for your time..:)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to use range : [db_select documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) and more precisely [range](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQueryExtender%3A%3Arange/7).

Comment: `range()` is just for basic limiting, the OP is trying to add a pager to the query

Comment: I up'd your answer, thx for the info Clive.